# Does Google Chrome Render Content Differently on Phone vs Tablet vs PC?

Tags: google-chrome

There's are some major differences between the way iPhone Safari, iPad Safari, and Mac Safari render HTML / CSS.  What about the differences between the way Chrome renders content on a phone vs a tablet vs a PC?  Do they warrant testing websites on all three versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled to this question, because I had problems that Google Chrome renders the same page different on tablets vs PC.

This was rendering differently:

1. fonts - there are other threads where people complain about different font rendering, i.e. [Chrome renders em based font sizes differently on devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14160931/chrome-renders-em-based-font-sizes-differently-on-devices) .
   In my experience, if you don't declare font sizes, on tablets `<p>` and `<div>` will have different font sizes!
2. `clear: both` on tablets did put one extra paragraph space (this was used in dropdown menu), which was not seen on a desktop version (I have no idea why this happens).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen yet but there are some responsive sites such as http://quirktools.com/screenfly/

or this site may help you

http://www.modern.ie/en-US/virtualization-tools

I haven't test it yet. I think there is a membership obligation for testing.